# push notifications using OSB

Tags: xml, push-notification, wsdl, schema, osb

In order to use the push notifications through OSB proxy web service, can some one advice how the web service structure should like for this (elements, attributes, operations) which are required to defined for a general push notification in the wsdl/schema, to support the maximum features of push notifications.

As we know to send an sms, mobile number and the text to send is mandatory in addition can set when it has to be delivered and for email to address, optional cc/bcc and email body is required, for push notifications what is the format and supporting structure?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is this an OSB question, a push notification question, or an API design question?

Comment: It is possible to use OSB to mediate push notifications to other devices.  The structures/formats depend on whether it is apple, android, etc. For example, the notification payload for the Apple push notification service is a  json dictionary object,  you need to read the documentation and specification of the payloads of each of devices that you manage and then come up with a specific solution.

Answer (score -1):

We implemented push notifications with `OSB` service the following way:

First decide about `JSON payload` format. You can find information about payload fields here: https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/client

`OSB` itself is relatively simple.
All that you need to do in main flow is to transform request to `JSON` with `XQuery` and call for `Google API`. My way is to call `Google` with `Java callout` and simple `HTTPUrlConnection` based client.
Mandatory fields that has to be passed to `OSB` are `Device ID` and your `Google account ID` (assuming you have one).

This flow is applicable both for `Android` and `iOs` devices. May be you will end up with having different `XQuery` and API endpoint for `iOs`.
However Google says that it is possible to send `iOs` messages with that same API but I haven't tried it. Hope it will help.